# Detect if there are changes in certain inputs

Tags: jquery, html

The concept is I would be creating this div with its div's id, input's id and name on increments. And the percent field should be able to detect if the inputs are being changed. How can I make this work? It seems to only work on the first input widget created.

```
<div id="divRdTest">
    <div class="form-group" id="rdTestFld1">
         <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2">
              <center>
                  <input type="text" id="txtRTName1" name="txtRTName1" class="form-control">
              </center>
         </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
         <center>
             <input type="text" id="txtRTPercent1" name="txtRTPercent1" class="form-control percent-compute">
             </center>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>


//The script 

$(".percent-compute").on("input", function(e){
    //computation code
});
```

Comment: Maybe try, `$(".percent-compute").on("change",function(e){});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your div's is created dynamically you must be use `document` selector on apply `input, change.`

```js
$(document).on("input change",".percent-compute", function(e){
   console.log($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divRdTest">
    <div class="form-group" id="rdTestFld1">
         <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2">
              <center>
                  <input type="text" id="txtRTName1" name="txtRTName1" class="form-control">
              </center>
         </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
         <center>
             <input type="text" id="txtRTPercent1" name="txtRTPercent1" class="form-control percent-compute">
             </center>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```